# How to create alphabet and Input Search in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am new in codeigniter4 I want to filter the list by alphabet and search input. On click of each alphabet, it should sort the list according to the alphabet. In my database product list is stored in JSON array format.

The below image to explain better

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/doU6l.jpg]

For example: If you click on "A" then it will display a list starting with "A" Like ( Apple, Airplane, Adidas ), etc. And the case should be the same when you input in the search input box.

Below is the render function in the controller which is  searching particular objects of the JSON array.

```
public function loadRecord(){
    $request = service('request');
    $searchData = $request->getGet();
    $search = "";
    if(isset($searchData) && isset($searchData['search']))
    {
       $search = $searchData['search'];
    }

    $model = new PageModel();

    if($search == ''){
        $paginateData = $model->paginate(5);
    } else {
        $db=\Config\Database::connect();

        $product_array = [];
        $query = $db->query('
            SELECT description->"$.products_title" as product_titles 
            FROM iolt_pages 
            WHERE description->"$.products_title" 
            LIKE "%'.$search.'%"
            AND pg_id=33'
        );
        $result = $query->getResult();
        $productData=json_decode($result[0]->product_titles);
        for($i=0;$i<count($productData);$i++)
        {
            if(strpos($productData[$i], $search) !== false)
            {
                $product_array[]=$productData[$i];
            } else {
                //echo "Word Not Found!<br>";
            }
        }         
        print_r($product_array);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
public function loadRecord() {
    $request = service('request');
    $searchData = $request->getGet();
    if(isset($searchData) && isset($searchData['search']))
    {
       $search = $searchData['search'];
    }
    $model = new PageModel();

    if(!empty($search)) {
        $model->like('description', $search, 'after');
    }
    $data = $model->asArray()->paginate(5);

    if(!empty($data)) {
        die('word not found');
    }
    dd($data);
}
```

There's no need for json for the filter, you can filter that with the like statement and you can keep adding to the model object with if statements and just run the query in the end. This way you don't need to have one query for all records and another for the filter, just add the filter if needed.

Also if you need an array instead of object you can do so in the model by changing the return type, this you can override by using the asArray() method that will return all data as an array. This way you don't need to iterate all the data to transform it from object to array.